# How to post a json / geojson in Postman with coordinates and Geography datatype

Tags: node.js, postgresql, leaflet, sequelize.js, postgis

I am trying to do an update posting on Postman for the first using PostGIS / Geography file type and I don't know where I am going wrong.

I have included the model below of the table in pgamdin 4 / postgres that I need the posting to go to as well as the json format. I know about GeoJson's but i'm not sure if these are just json's with coordinates. I am trying to pull object description details along with the co-ordinates so i can display them on the marker.

Am i going about this the right way?

My json posting that isn't working is below:

```
{
    "diveSchoolName": "Forever Dive",
    "diveSchoolLocation": "Madagascar",
    "diveSchoolRegionID": 5,
    "diveCertificatesOfferedID": 1,
    "diveSpotsOfferedID": 1,
    "diveSchoolGeo": {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geography": {
            "type": "Geography",
            "coordinates": [-18.7669, 46.8691]
        }    
    }
    }
```

model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {

    const approvedDivingSchool = sequelize.define("approvedDivingSchools", {

        diveSchoolID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        diveSchoolName: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        },
        diveSchoolLocation: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        },
        diveSchoolRegionID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        diveCoursesOffered: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        diveSpotsOfferedID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        diveSchoolGeo: {
            type: Sequelize.GEOGRAPHY
        }},
        {
            timestamps: false
        })

    return approvedDivingSchool;
};
```

Error message on postman console

```
PUT /api/auth/updatediveschool HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: db7ac983-c1e4-4a5a-bb5d-990f31dbc337
Host: localhost:5002
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 365
{
    "diveSchoolName": "Forever Dive",
    "diveSchoolLocation": "Madagascar",
    "diveSchoolRegionID": 5,
    "diveCertificatesOfferedID": 1,
    "diveSpotsOfferedID": 1,
    "diveSchoolGeo": {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geography": {
            "type": "Geography",
            "coordinates": [-18.7669, 46.8691]
        }    
    }
    }
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 164
Date: Tue, 19 Jan 2021 00:12:34 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot PUT /api/auth/updatediveschool</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 404 doesn't seem like to be problem with your geojson. nonetheless, your geojson should probably be like
```
    "diveSchoolGeo": {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-18.7669, 46.8691]
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Do the GeoJSON details all get added to the one field in the postgres table? I have it set up to pull information from across the table but from what i can see i would be duplicating as the info is already in the geojson.